# Deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations) in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, cascading-deletes, delete-record

I keep getting this error when trying to delete a record from my table. Insert and Update work fine apart from delete.

Here is my set up:

Mappings:

```
 HasMany(x => x.Items).AsList().AsBag().LazyLoad().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

GetMethod:

```
  IRepositoryWithTypedId<BOD.Entities.Item, Guid> Rep = RepositoryFinder.For<BOD.Entities.Item, Guid>();
         BOD.Entities.Item tag = Rep.Get(new Guid("0A495241-082F-4314-8B79-000A524FC666"));

         Rep.Delete(tag);
```

I have also tried using:

```
 Repository().DbContext.CommitTransaction();
 Repository().DbContext.CommitChanges();
```

These two still cause errors. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, get rid of the `AsList()` call in your mapping, unless you want it to be mapped as an nhibernate list (ie with an index column). The `AsBag()` call is overriding it, but you don't want to specify two different collection mapping specifications.

Comment: it wasn't supposed to fix your problem, just something for you to be aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because `tag` is contained in some collection, you should remove it from that collection to actually delete it. Otherwise when you persist the collecting entity, the tag will be saved again.